# Is there an Angular directive behaving like ngFor with exactly one element?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a component that displays some data of a particular object in a certain context (i.e. in another component). In addition to displaying the data, there is some setup and tearing down upon initialization and destruction respectively.

I would like to have the component destroyed and reinitialized when its input (the displayed object) changes. However, this cannot be accomplished with a simple binding. To guarantee that setup and tear down happens on input change, I would have to watch for changes in `ngOnChanges` and implement `ngOnDestroy` as well (initialization could be covered in `ngOnChanges`) but I'd rather implement only `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` and create a new instance of the component when the main input binding changes.

I think I could achieve this behaviour with a "single-element `ngFor`" but I would have to wrap my object in an array. Is there a better way? Maybe there is already a directive I don't know or I can use `ngFor` in a clever way. I want to avoid that the controller has to know the wrapper array.

Comment: I think wrapping your single value in an array would be the simplest way. You can also have a look at `*ngIf` and implement a similar structural directive yourself that removes and adds a component when an input changes.

Comment: Thanks, implementing it myself sounds like a good idea for learning Angular better.